# jquery gridview

Tags: asp.net

On my pages, ASP.NET 3.5 I have hyperlinks, both inside and outside the gridviews.  Is there any way to determine which type was clicked - inside or outside? All GridViews have same CssClass but I don't want to use CssClass for any elements inside the grid.

```
$("a").click(function(e)
{
     //this attribute doesn't exist this is just to give an idea
     if($(this).attr('ParentClass') = "GridViewClass")  
     {

     }
     else
     {

     }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this selector.

```
$('.GridViewClass a')
```

Comment: LOL. I was typing out this long winded thing using .parent() and .hasClass() when you posted this. I feel silly now.